# Is there any difference initializing array by enumaration XOR new type[] + enumaration?

Tags: java, arrays, charsequence

Is there any difference between those to initializations of array?

```
CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};
CharSequence colors[] = {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not. They will be compiled into the same byte code.

For reference, the [Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

> An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10) or an
>   array initializer (§10.6).

where [array creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10), ie. the `new CharSequence[]` part, is defined as

```
ArrayCreationExpression:
    new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
    new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

DimExprs:
    DimExpr
    DimExprs DimExpr

DimExpr:
    [ Expression ]

Dims:
    [ ]
    Dims [ ]
```

and [array initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), ie. the `{...}` part, is defined as

```
ArrayInitializer:
    { VariableInitializersopt ,opt }

VariableInitializers:
    VariableInitializer
    VariableInitializers , VariableInitializer  

VariableInitializer:
    Expression
    ArrayInitializer
```